# How to have 3 condition inside if statement for user input JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

JavaScript: I want to check if the user input meets 3 conditions on an if statement. I don't know how to make `&&` and `|` work on a single if statement. I have the `|` after the first condition but the `&&` is not taken into consideration and I can leave the input box empty and it will still redirect me to the page. I tried multiple ways but I did not get it to work. Please help and thank you in advance.

**JavaScript**

```
    function valForm() {
          var firstVal = document.getElementById("nextId").value;
          var secondVal = document.getElementById("licenseId").value;
          if (
            (firstVal == "MB3804") | (firstVal == "mb3804") &&
            (secondVal.length == 6) | 7
          ) {
            window.location.href = "google.com";
          }
        }
```

**HTML**

```
      <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="License Plate"
          id="licensed"
          autocomplete="off"
      />
      <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Ticket ID"
          id="nextId"
          autocomplete="off"
      />
      <button class="btn btn-primary display-4" type="button" onclick="valForm()">next</button>
```

Comment: `(firstVal == "MB3804") | (firstVal == "mb3804")`: NO!!!!  Use "||", not "|"!  You need [logical or](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) "||", not the [bitwise or](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR) "|".  Better: just do a case-insensitive string compare: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/compare-strings-ignore-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (
    (firstVal == "MB3804") | (firstVal == "mb3804") &&
    (secondVal.length == 6) | 7
)
```

should probably be

```
if (
    (firstVal === "MB3804" || firstVal == "mb3804") &&
    (secondVal.length === 6 || secondVal.length === 7)
)
```

There are few things to notice here:

- The use of `===` instead of `==` : see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness
- The use of `||` ([the logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)) instead of `|` ([the bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR))
- Parenthesis placement helps make clear the order of operations

paulsm's comment above is also quite valid and you could use a case-insensitive string comparison instead of 2 separate comparisons if that makes sense in your case. Of course if you want the condition to succeed for `MB3804` and `mb3804` but fail for `Mb3804` and `mB3804`, then the case-insensitive string comparison will not be appropriate, but if all four cases are considered "good" then it makes a lot of sense and

```
if (firstVal === "MB3804" || firstVal === "mb3804") {...}
```

could be rewritten as

```
if (firstVal.toLowerCase() === "mb3804") {...}
```